# While logged in, how to detect preview/draft/live?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

While using Apostrophe Workflow, I don't know how to detect in CSS and/or JavaScript in which mode the user is viewing the page.

[image]

The `.apos-workflow-draft-page` CSS class seems to be present in  both draft and preview modes, and this can cause problems. We improved the visibility and the layout of certain elements so they are understood as editable while in draft, however in preview, we wish to not show all these hints.

What would be the ApostropheCMS' way to properly detect these states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect `apos.modules['apostrophe-workflow'].locale`, which will end in `-draft` if in draft mode:

```js
if (apos.modules['apostrophe-workflow'].locale.match(/-draft$/)) {
  // draft mode
} else {
  // live mode
}
```

Detecting preview mode is easy too. First check for draft mode, then check `data.workflowPreview` anywhere in your template:

```
data.workflowPreview
```

This isn't pushed into a frontend javascript variable, but you can do it yourself:

```
<script>
window.workflowPreview = {{ data.workflowPreview | json }};
</script>
```

Comment: But how do I make a distinction between preview and draft? There are 3 options in the workflow, and this check offers only two.

Comment: This is still a good option for the draft vs live mode though, dont get me wrong :)

Comment: Whoops, missed that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yup, this worked. I created a method to get the mode in a self contained way: https://github.com/jansensan/arts-et-medias/blob/master/lib/modules/aem-utils/index.js#L101 This way I can obtain it in the templates, which is where I needed the thing. Thanks, I set marked your response as accepted.